# How do you check if an array has some integers and then add them all up to get a result

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot2 = new Discord.Client();


const mark = '*interesting';
const marker = '*reverse'
const markir = '*fakereverse'
const markri = '*falsereverse'
const markre = '*randomise_'
const mrk = '*replace_'
const markro ='*math'
let para_meter = false
function reverseString(str) {
   return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}
function randomise(str) {
   randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length)
   strarr = str.split('')
   alphabet = ['A', 'a', 'B','b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'V', 'v', 'W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Z', 'z']
   alpharandom = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * 52)]
   strarr[randomnumber] = alpharandom
   return strarr.join('')
}

bot2.on('message', msg =>{
   
   let args = msg.content.substring(mark.length)
   let sgra = msg.content.substring(marker.length)
   let thisis = msg.content.substring(markir.length)
   let sisiht = msg.content.substring(markri.length)
   let argon = msg.content.substring(markre.length)   
   let goodgood = msg.content.substring(mrk.length)
   let spited = msg.content.split(' ')
   
   if(msg.content.startsWith(mark)){
      let thee = args + ". I'm not dad. I'm bad discord bot"
      msg.channel.send(thee)
   }
   if(msg.content.startsWith(marker)){
      if(sgra == ''){
         msg.channel.send('you need something to reverse')
         return
      }
      let arg = reverseString(sgra)
      msg.channel.send(arg)
   }
   if(msg.content.startsWith(markir)){
      if(thisis == ''){
         msg.channel.send('you need something to fakereverse')
         return
      }
      let tese = thisis.split(' ')
      let arrayI = []
      tese.forEach(thing => {
         arrayI.push(reverseString(thing))
      })
      msg.channel.send(arrayI.join(' '))
      
   }
   if(msg.content.startsWith(markri)){
      if(sisiht == ''){
         msg.channel.send('you need something to falsereverse')
         return
      }
      let eset = sisiht.split(' ')
      let arrayII = []
      eset.forEach(gniht => {
         arrayII.push(reverseString(gniht))
      })
      let somethingi = arrayII.join(' ')
      msg.channel.send(reverseString(somethingi))
   }
   if(msg.content.startsWith(markre)){
      if(argon == ''){
         msg.channel.send('you need something to randomise')
         return
      }
      let esci = argon.split(' ')
      let arrayIII = []
      esci.forEach(thing => {
         let thingo = randomise(thing)
         arrayIII.push(thingo)
      })
      msg.channel.send(arrayIII.join(' '))
   }
   if(msg.content.startsWith(mrk)){
      if(goodgood == ''){
         msg.channel.send('you need some words to replace')
         return
      }
      let doog = goodgood.split(' ')
      let arrayIV = []
      doog.forEach(item => {
         switch(item.length){
            case 0:
               arrayIV.push(' ')
               break;
            case 1:
               arrayIV.push('a')
               break;
            case 2:
               arrayIV.push('an')
               break;
            case 3:
               arrayIV.push('the')
               break;
            case 4:
               arrayIV.push('what')
               break;
            case 5:
               arrayIV.push('where')
               break;
            case 6:
               arrayIV.push('flight')
               break;
            case 7:
               arrayIV.push('amazing')
               break;
            case 8:
               arrayIV.push('censored')
               break;
            case 9:
               arrayIV.push('wordcount')
               break;
            case 10:
               arrayIV.push('everything')
               break;
            case 11:
               arrayIV.push('magnificent')
               break;
            case 12:
               arrayIV.push('mitochondria')
               break;
            case 13:
               arrayIV.push('unlucky_number')
               break;
            default:
               fakearray = ['\nAccording to all known laws', 'of aviation,', '', '', 'there is no way a bee', 'should be able to fly.', '', '','Its wings are too small to get','its fat little body off the ground.', '', '',`because bees don't care`,'what humans think is impossible.\n'  ]
               fakestring = fakearray.join('\n')
               arrayIV.push(fakestring)
               break;
         }
      

      })
      msg.channel.send(arrayIV.join(' '))
   }
   if(spited[0] == markro){
      if(!spited[1]){
         msg.reply('there needs to be a math function to use')
         return;
      }
      switch (spited[1]) {
         case 'add':
            if(!spited[2]){
               msg.reply('you need something to add') 
            } else {
               let thestuff = msg.content.split(' ').splice(markro, 1).splice('add', 1)
               thestuff.forEach(elem => {
                  if(!isNaN(elem)){
                     para_meter = true
                  }
               })
               if(para_meter == true){
                  msg.reply('these are not integers')
                  para_meter = false
                  return;
               }
               var reduced = 0
               thestuff.forEach(eleme => {
                  reduced += eleme
               })
               msg.channel.send(reduced)

            }

            break;
      
         default:
            break;
      }

   }
   
   
  

  
})
 


bot2.login(process.env.token2)
```

Focus on the last command. That is where I get my problem. In it I try to detect if a message has *math add in the start. Then I try check if the message has non-integers words(by turning the message into an array) and then I try to(if all the words are all integers) add up them and get a result I can send as a message. Here's the command that has the problem

```
 if(spited[0] == markro){
      if(!spited[1]){
         msg.reply('there needs to be a math function to use')
         return;
      }
      switch (spited[1]) {
         case 'add':
            if(!spited[2]){
               msg.reply('you need something to add') 
            } else {
               let thestuff = msg.content.split(' ').splice(markro, 1).slice('add', 1)
               thestuff.forEach(elem => {
                  if(!isNaN(elem)){
                     para_meter = true
                  }
               })
               if(para_meter == true){
                  msg.reply('these are not integers')
                  para_meter = false
                  return;
               }
               var reduced = 0
               thestuff.forEach(eleme => {
                  reduced += eleme
               })
               msg.channel.send(reduced)

            }

            break;
      
         default:
            break;
      }

   }
```

Whenever I actually try use it though the bots command it just responds with '0*math'. How do I fix this

(I'm grateful that long code is scrollable and is not in one block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***See update at the bottom of this answer***

If you wanted to add all numbers together from an array, you could use reduce to do so.  Just check for the type before adding.

Something like this should do the trick..

*Original answer:*

```js
// ~ Original ~
//  * Numbers are typed as such (not strings)
/** const myArray = [{}, [], "a", 1, "b", 3, "c", 5]; **/

// ~ Updated ~
//  * Numbers are in string form (same as you are 
//    receiving the data from the API)
const myArray = [{}, [], "a", "1", "b", "3", "c", "5"]; 

const result = addNumbers(myArray); 

console.log(result); // 9

function addNumbers (arr = []) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
    throw new Error(
      `[addNumbers] Parameter type is '${typeof arr}', need Array!`
    );
  }
  
  return arr.reduce((a, v) => 
    (isNaN(Number.parseInt(v)) ? 0 : Number(v)) + a, 0);
}
```

---

---

***UPDATE 1***

*Rethinking the current solution as a whole*

From what I can tell, whether it is for addition, multiplication, etc.. you are expecting a specific string. This means there is no need to iterate over an array..

Example:

```js
// Set default value for input/query 
setQuery("add");

/**
 * parseInput is our main function that parses "chat" commands
 */
function parseInput(inputStr) {
  // Replace multiple spaces with single space
  // In case someone types '*math     add      3        3' or something
  const inputStrSingleSpaced = inputStr.replace(/\s\s+/g, " ");

  // Turn our string into an array
  const inputArr = inputStrSingleSpaced.split(" ");

  // Our array should contain 4 elements regardless of operation (add/multiply/etc)
  if (inputArr.length !== 4) return undefined; // Could throw an error here?

  const firstNum = Number(inputArr[2]); // First number should always be 3rd element in array
  const secondNum = Number(inputArr[3]); // You get the idea..
  const operation = inputArr[1];

  switch (operation) {
    case "add": return firstNum + secondNum;
    case "multiply": return firstNum * secondNum;
    // case "subtract": ...etc
    default: return undefined; // Throw an error if you want instead?
  }
}


/**
 * sendIt "sends" our chat/query string for parsing
 */
function sendIt() {
  const el = document.querySelector("#textbox");
  const resEl = document.querySelector("#results");
  const calculation = parseInput(el.value);
  resEl.innerHTML = `<h1>Result: ${calculation}</h1>`;
}


/**
 * setQuery lets us set the input value to a demo query string
 */
function setQuery(kind) {
  const el = document.querySelector("#textbox");
  if (kind === "add") el.value = `*math add ${rando()} ${rando()}`;
  if (kind === "add_with_spaces") el.value = `*math    add        ${rando()}       ${rando()}`;
  if (kind === "multiply") el.value = `*math multiply ${rando()} ${rando()}`;
}

/**
 * rando returns a random number between 0 and 50
 */
function rando() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
}
```

```css
.mt20 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Enter query string (simulating chatting) then hit 'Send'</h3>
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<button onclick="sendIt()">Send</button>

<hr />

<div id="results" class="mt20"></div>

<hr />

<div class="mt20">
  Example Queries: <small><i>Click one to set query</i></small>
  <br />
  <button onclick="setQuery('add')">Add</button>
  <button onclick="setQuery('multiply')">Multiply</button>
  <button onclick="setQuery('add_with_spaces')">Multiple Spaces</button>
</div>
```

---

---

***UPDATE 2:***

If you wanted to mirror the `addNumbers` function, but for multiplication:

```js
const myArray = [{}, [], "a", "9", "b", "3", "c"]; 

const result = multiplyNumbers(myArray); 

console.log(result); // 27

function multiplyNumbers (arr = []) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
    throw new Error(
      `[multiplyNumbers] Parameter type is '${typeof arr}', need Array!`
    );
  }
  
  return arr.reduce((a, v) => {
    if (!isNaN(Number.parseInt(v))) { // If we are able to parse the string into an int
      if (a === 0) return Number(v); // If accumulator is 0, just return current value (don't want to multiply by 0)
      return Number(v) * Number(a); // If accumulator is NOT 0, multiply
    }
    return Number(a);
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: it is always giving me zero now

Comment: I made it only be the integers but it still only shows 0

Comment: I think what's happening is when you type the API doesn't return an integer as such, it returns it as a string. This is obvious to me now... Can you show what the string looks like that you get? Something like `*math add 2 2`?

Comment: I firstly figured out how to get everything after the *math add
I made it be logged on the console
`[ '1', '2' ]

0`
Yep it is stored as a string. How do I make it not do that

Comment: I made it so it uses slice(1,1) to times to remove the two first words. The array is the first part and the result is the second one.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working solution. If the string can be converted to a number, we convert it then add it...

Comment: is there anyway to use something like this to get a muiltiplying function(a function like this but instead of adding its multiplying)

Comment: any response from anyone

Comment: (but is there anyway of using a similar thing for multiplying)

Comment: Is there anyway of making a function like the old awnser but it does multiplying(I want to be able to multiply multiple numbers together like the old addition function).

Comment: That's exactly what my example shows you how to do...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217036/discussion-between-mataldin-and-matt-oestreich).

Comment: @mataldin Please see my updated answer. Specifically, UPDATE 2.

Comment: thanks for the 2nd uptade. I would give you another thanks reaction if I could.

Comment: Now that I have way more knowledge about js I feel like I maybe should of not just copy and pasted this in the first place.

Comment: @mataldin what do you mean? Are you saying copying and pasting code from online isn't safe?...or that my code sucks? lol

Comment: I maybe should of tried understand the code before I just used it. I am surprised you responded